# Slow loading React Native Ad Mob Banner ads

Tags: react-native, admob, react-native-google-mobile-ads

I am displaying banner ads using react native google mobile ads: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads.  When I display banner ads, the ad takes about 5 seconds before it displays on the screen. Is there anything i can do to speed the process up, so the ad shows much quicker?

I am initializing mobile ads soon as possible in a start screen prior to the screen where ads are displayed.

```
mobileAds().initialize()
```

Is there a way to preload the banner ads?

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this?

Comment: no, not yet @Cory